# ES6 import/export variable is undefined after importing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules, javascript-import

I'm trying to use Javascript import/export to import a simple variable.

test.html

```
<script src="js/launch/test1.js" type="module"></script>
```

test1.js

```
import myTestVar from "./test2.js";

console.log(myTestVar); // undefined
```

test2.js

```
export default myTestVar;
var myTestVar = "test!";
```

However, in `test1.js`, `myTestVar` is undefined.

Comment: why are you exporting it before defining it?  try your export statement *after* `var myTestVar = "test!";`

Comment: because i made a silly mistake. :D

Comment: You could also do `export { myTestVar as default };` if you really want to declare it above the initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the order of the statements:

```
var myTestVar = "test!";
export default myTestVar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is equivalent to

```
export default undefined;
var myTestVar = "test!";
```

or

```
var myTestVar;
export default myTestVar;
myTestVar = "test!";
```

If you really want to export the variable, not just its current value, you should write

```
export { myTestVar as default }
var myTestVar = "test!";
```

Answer (score -1):

You can make test2.js like:

```
export var test = "hello world";
export var secondVar = "hello world 2";
```

and import it like

```
import { test, secondVar } from './test2.js'
```